# Input string was not in a correct format when using WebUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: c#

I'm been getting an exception from [WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and I'm not sure why (although I suspect it's something simple my caffeine deprived brain is missing). The documentation states it expects UTF-8, so I did a conversion and still no love:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
   at System.Console.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
   at testApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\VisualStudio\testApp\testApp\Program.cs:line 18
```

Here is a sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;    

namespace testApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            String url = "This is a URL to Encode%!";
            Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(url.ToCharArray());
            String utfUrl = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            Console.WriteLine(utfUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("Encoded: {}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(utfUrl));
            Console.WriteLine("Decoded: {}", WebUtility.UrlDecode(utfUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `0` (the index of the format string parameter) in your `Console.WriteLine` calls:

```
Console.WriteLine("Encoded: {0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(utfUrl));
Console.WriteLine("Decoded: {0}", WebUtility.UrlDecode(utfUrl));
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The syntax of a format item is `{index[,alignment][:formatString]}`,
>   **which specifies a mandatory index**, the optional length and alignment
>   of the formatted text, and an optional string of format specifier
>   characters that govern how the value of the corresponding object is
>   formatted.

Comment: Ahahahaha and now I go get a coffee... Thanks :-)